# How to update table in mysql using subquery of same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table called **my_data** as like below:

```
 +-------+-------+--------+
 | attr1 | attr2 | att3   |
 +-------+-------+--------+
 |   3   |   1   |    1   |
 |   4   |   2   |    1   |
 |   5   |   3   |    1   |
 |   3   |   6   |    1   |
 |   3   |   7   |    1   |
 |   3   |   8   |    1   |
 |   8   |   8   |    1   |
 |   9   |   7   |    1   |
 |   3   |   9   |    1   |
 +-------+-------+--------+
```

I need to do this:

```
UPDATE my_data 
SET 
    attr3 = 0 
WHERE (attr1, attr2) IN (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM my_data GROUP BY attr1);
```

In mysql, update won't work with select statement in it. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: what u want in your update? i dont understand what u want to do in your sql

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN the my_data with the inner query and update the attr3 as follows:

```
UPDATE my_data a
JOIN (SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM my_data GROUP BY attr1) b
ON a.attr1 = b.attr1 AND a.attr2 = b.attr1
SET a.attr3 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Staring at the above data, my guess that you want to update `attr3` to 0 for any `attr1` that has multiple `attr2` values.

If that is the case, the query should count how many `attr2` there are:

```
UPDATE
    (SELECT attr1,COUNT(attr2) attr2count FROM my_data
    GROUP BY attr1 HAVING COUNT(attr2) > 1) A
    INNER JOIN my_data B USING (attr1)
SET B.attr3 = 0;
```

I chose `SELECT ... GROUP BY ... HAVING` because it is more stable that `SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM my_data GROUP BY attr1` in that `attr2` would be only one of the numbers that `attr1` is duplicated by.

According to the MySQL Documentation on `GROUP BY`, [there is no guarantee which value mysql chooses when using `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html).

[**I had answered a question in the DBA StackExchange about this controversial reliance on the order of a `GROUP BY`.**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29321/877)

If you know for a certainty that you want for `attr1=3` that the row with the minimum `attr2` is to have the attr3 set to 0, then the answer to your question would be this:

```
UPDATE
    (SELECT attr1,MIN(attr2) attr2 FROM my_data
    GROUP BY attr1 HAVING COUNT(attr2) > 1) A
    INNER JOIN my_data B USING (attr1,attr2)
SET B.attr3 = 0;
```

Let's test them both:

## TESTING FIRST QUERY

First here is the sample data:

```
drop database if exists clickit;
create database clickit;
use clickit
create table my_data (attr1 INT,attr2 INT,attr3 INT);
insert into my_data values
(3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,3,1),
(3,6,1),(3,7,1),(3,8,1),
(8,8,1),(9,7,1),(3,9,1);
```

Here is the sample data loaded:

```
mysql> drop database if exists clickit;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> create database clickit;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use clickit
Database changed
mysql> create table my_data (attr1 INT,attr2 INT,attr3 INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into my_data values
    -> (3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,3,1),
    -> (3,6,1),(3,7,1),(3,8,1),
    -> (8,8,1),(9,7,1),(3,9,1);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_data;
+-------+-------+-------+
| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     1 |     1 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     3 |     6 |     1 |
|     3 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     8 |     1 |
|     8 |     8 |     1 |
|     9 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     9 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the first query I suggested:

```
mysql>     UPDATE
    ->         (SELECT attr1,COUNT(attr2) attr2count FROM my_data
    ->         GROUP BY attr1 HAVING COUNT(attr2) > 1) A
    ->         INNER JOIN my_data B USING (attr1)
    ->     SET B.attr3 = 0;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

mysql>     select * from my_data;
+-------+-------+-------+
| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     1 |     0 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     3 |     6 |     0 |
|     3 |     7 |     0 |
|     3 |     8 |     0 |
|     8 |     8 |     1 |
|     9 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     9 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The first changed attr3 to 0 for attr1 that has multiple rows

## TESTING SECOND QUERY

Let's reload the sample and run the second query:

```
mysql> drop database if exists clickit;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> create database clickit;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use clickit
Database changed
mysql> create table my_data (attr1 INT,attr2 INT,attr3 INT
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into my_data values
    -> (3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,3,1),
    -> (3,6,1),(3,7,1),(3,8,1),
    -> (8,8,1),(9,7,1),(3,9,1);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_data;
+-------+-------+-------+
| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     1 |     1 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     3 |     6 |     1 |
|     3 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     8 |     1 |
|     8 |     8 |     1 |
|     9 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     9 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     UPDATE
    ->         (SELECT attr1,MIN(attr2) attr2 FROM my_data
    ->         GROUP BY attr1 HAVING COUNT(attr2) > 1) A
    ->         INNER JOIN my_data B USING (attr1,attr2)
    ->     SET B.attr3 = 0;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_data;
+-------+-------+-------+
| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     1 |     0 |
|     4 |     2 |     1 |
|     5 |     3 |     1 |
|     3 |     6 |     1 |
|     3 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     8 |     1 |
|     8 |     8 |     1 |
|     9 |     7 |     1 |
|     3 |     9 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!